# Stratified sampling based on two population benchmark distributions

Tags: r, sampling, survey

I am having trouble figuring out an existing way or writing new code to use stratified sampling from a dataset `framework` against two different population benchmark distributions. Since I am not 100% sure I am using the right terminology, I will explain more concretely with a simplified example:

I have a dataset with panel members of whom I know the gender and education level, the sampling `framework`. I want to draw a sample from there using stratified sampling. I know the population distribution of `gender`, and the distribution of `education`, but not the joint distribution (and I am not willing to assume that education is identically distributed among genders). Using stratified sampling, I want to end up with a sample that is (roughly) representative on these two benchmarks.

I provide code below to show how I would sample on one distribution (`gender`). I know there exist functions such as in the sampling package that simplify stratified sampling, but as far as I understand, they are not equipped for stratified sampling with two marginal distributions.

```
library(dplyr)

N = 1000 # framework size
n = 300 # sample size

# create sampling framework
framework = data.frame(id        = seq(1:N),
                       gender    = sample(c("M","F"), N, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7)),
                       education = sample(c("1. Low", "2. Mid", "3. High"), N, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5)))

# create population benchmarks
pop_gender    = data.frame(gender    = c("M", "F"),
                           prop      = c(0.5, 0.5))
pop_education = data.frame(education = c("1. Low", "2. Mid", "3. High"),
                           prop      = c(0.4, 0.3, 0.3))

# loop through strata (in this case just M/F) and select sample
selected = NA # empty selection vector
for(i in pop_gender$gender){
  # subset framework to stratum
  framework_sel = framework %>%
    filter(gender == i) 
  
  # select sample from stratum
  selected_i = sample(framework_sel$id, # sample from ids
                      n*pop_gender$prop[pop_gender$gender == i], # sample size within stratum
                      replace = FALSE)
  selected = c(selected, selected_i)
}

# pull sample from framework
sample = framework %>%
  filter(id %in% selected)

# compare sample to population
prop.table(table(sample$gender))
prop.table(table(sample$education))
```

To be clear: I'd like to end up with a sample that matches the population on both gender and education.

I appreciate any insights!

---

An additional wrinkle that I have not included in this simplified example is that it is very likely the framework will not have sufficient people in some strata to be sampled to the intended stratum sample size.

Answer (score 2):

Cube sampling, as in `sampling::samplecube` does sampling to match multiple margins.

I think it's more common in practice to sample to match only one margin and then post-stratify/rake to match the other margin.

Answer (score 0):

The code below samples from `framework` stratified by gender and education.
The sample **does not match** the population on both gender and education. It will try to match the probabilities in `pop_gender` and `pop_education`. But even then there is randomness in the final result and it is not exactly the wanted one.

```r
N <- 1000 # framework size
n <- 300 # sample size

# create population benchmarks
pop_gender    = data.frame(gender    = c("M", "F"),
                           prop      = c(0.5, 0.5))
pop_education = data.frame(education = c("1. Low", "2. Mid", "3. High"),
                           prop      = c(0.4, 0.3, 0.3))

library(sampling)

# make results reproducible, the code below
# uses randomness twice, one in the call to 
# stats::r2dtable and the other in the call
# to sampling::strata
set.seed(2023)

# total to sample by gender and education
marg_gender <- pop_gender$prop * n
marg_education <- pop_education$prop * n

# account for the possibility that the framework does not
# have sufficient people in some strata to be sampled 
# to the intended stratum sample size.
tbl <- table(framework[-1])
marg_gender <- pmin(marg_gender, rowSums(tbl))
marg_education <- pmin(marg_education, colSums(tbl))

# Random 2-way table with given marginals
sample_sizes <- r2dtable(1L, marg_gender, marg_education) |> unlist()

# stratified sampling without replacement
s <- strata(framework, c("gender", "education"), size = sample_sizes, method = "srswor")
# extract the sampled rows to a new data.frame
sample2 <- getdata(framework, s)

# see the results, the final proportions are
# not exactly the wanted proportions

# first gender
cbind(
  wanted = pop_gender$prop, 
  prop = prop.table(table(sample2$gender)) |> round(2)
)
#>   wanted prop
#> F    0.5 0.55
#> M    0.5 0.45

# and education
cbind(
  wanted = pop_education$prop, 
  prop = prop.table(table(sample2$education)) |> round(2)
)
#>         wanted prop
#> 1. Low     0.4 0.30
#> 2. Mid     0.3 0.36
#> 3. High    0.3 0.35

head(sample2)
#>      id gender education ID_unit     Prob Stratum
#> 10   10      F    2. Mid      10 0.328125       1
#> 101 101      F    2. Mid     101 0.328125       1
#> 116 116      F    2. Mid     116 0.328125       1
#> 120 120      F    2. Mid     120 0.328125       1
#> 138 138      F    2. Mid     138 0.328125       1
#> 146 146      F    2. Mid     146 0.328125       1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

`framework` created with `set.seed` to make the results reproducible.

```r
N <- 1000 # framework size
n <- 300 # sample size

prob_gender <- c(0.3, 0.7)
prob_education <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5)

# create sampling framework
set.seed(1)
framework = data.frame(id        = seq(1:N),
                       gender    = sample(c("M","F"), N, replace = TRUE, prob = prob_gender),
                       education = sample(c("1. Low", "2. Mid", "3. High"), N, 
                                          replace = TRUE, prob = prob_education))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>